# How can I compare a boxplot to a histogram?

Tags: statistics

[image]

[image]

I'm really confused because for question 5 the solution says "Looking at areas under the curve $Q_1$ appears to be around 20, the median is around 30 and $Q_3$ is about 40."

I don't know what they are talking about with the area under the curve. I know the distribution is symmetric and looks normal so that's why I would assume the median is 30, etc..

But I cannot apply the same logic to question 6, in which case I have to use this "area under the curve" idea. I don't see how I can evenly break up all the bars into even squares to then see how many squares are in each bar and therefore how much area one bar takes up.

For question 6, the solution is "Looking at areas under the curve, $Q_1$ appears to be around 10, the median is around 30 and $Q_3$ is about 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both given histograms are symmetric with respect to $30$. So, the median (the central value) of the data must lie by $30$.

The box of the boxplot stands for around $50\%$ of the data (the mass of data from the lower to the upper quartile).

Looking at the first diagram and comparing the sizes of the bars you see that in the first histogram about $50\%$ of the data spreads from $20$ to $40$. So, boxplot $B$ is correct.

Similarly, in the second histogram about $50\%$ of the data spreads from $10$ to $50$. So, boxplot $C$ is correct.

Comment: sorry i think i just can't see it but when you said comparing the sizes of the bars in the first diagram, you can see that 50% spreads from 20 to 40 i don't see it. and same thing for the second one, i dont see how 50% of the data spreads from 10 to 50.

Comment: and why does the solution talk about the "area under the curve"? i still don't understand that part either

Comment: In a histogram the height of a bar represents the percentage of the data within the corresponding interval. Of course in an histogram you never know exactly where the data is located within such an interval. So, you have only "reasonable estimates".

Comment: so you are estimating that the tallest bar is 25%?

Comment: and when you add the second and third tallest bar you get another 25%?

Comment: i have no idea how to estimate these bars

Comment: So, the area of the bars sums up to $100\%$. Another way to look at it is with respect to the width of the box is as follows: The wider the spread of the data, the longer must be the box of the boxplot. Obviously the second histogram has a much wider spread of data than the first one.

Comment: sorry again but why is it obvious that the second histogram has a much wider spread than the first one? they both have values from 0 to 60

Comment: Concerning the estimate in the first diagram: the two leftmost bars have together a height of around the third one.So, yes, this gives you an estimate, that the two highest bars in the middle amount to about $50\%$ of the data.

Comment: so in general i have to just make it fit like pieces of a puzzle to see what percentage each bar represents? this kind of sucks lol i can't estimate these things so well.

Comment: In the second one about $50\%$ of the data lies relatively far away from the mean which is because of the symmetry of the data around the median. Or, as you can see, you need the 4 bars around the median to represent about $50\%$ of the data. So, the so called inter-quartile range is larger than the one in the first histogram.

Comment: The comparison with a puzzle is correct. it is like mentally "seeing" (estimating), where $50\%$ or $25\%$ of tha data may lie.

Comment: oh i see, can i also think about it like this: the standard deviation measures the average distance from the mean and since there is a higher frequency in the second graph at the ends, this means that the distance from the mean must be bigger than in the first graph? so thats why the second histogram has a wider spread than the first?

Comment: Yeah. If you know already the standard deviation, this is a correct argument. Obviously the standard deviation of the second one is higher than the standard deviation of the first one.

Comment: ok thank you so much!

Comment: you are welcome.